# How to detect drag operation on NSOutlineView (Snow Leopard)

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsoutlineview

I've a NSOutlineView used as file path drag source, it supports copy and move operations and are defined as shown below

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingSourceOperationMaskForLocal:(BOOL)flag {
    return NSDragOperationCopy | NSDragOperationMove;
}
```

When I drag filenames to Finder to move them I must refresh the UI to remove from outlineview the items but how can I detect user has 'moved' instead of 'copied' (eg hold down alt key)?